# Remover 2 caracteres específicos de uma String

Tags: java, android, string

Boa tarde !
Devs, não estou conseguindo resolver o seguinte problema:
Em um app de calculadora, o calculos sempre retornam um Double, que insere automaticamente uma casa decimal mesmo que seja para implantar o zero, e para mostrar no editText gostaria de remover o ".0" quando fosse mostrar o resultado;
por exemplo: a função calcular retorna um double nesta chamada:
somar(3, 4) retorna 7.0;
esse retorno eu converto em String e mando para o EditText.setText("7.0");

O que eu preciso:
criar um algoritmo que verifique os dois ultimos char dessa string, se forem igual a ".0", então eu retorno a string sem eles, com um replace por exemplo, mas apenas se esses forem exatamente os dois ultimos caracteres:
Isso é o que eu tenho até agora, porém se o valor for "100.07" ele retorna errôneamente "1007";

```
private String convertInt(Double duplo){
    return String.valueOf(duplo).replace(".0", "");
}
```

Comment: De maneira simples, o que voce quer é: Transforma double em string<br>
Substring dos ultimos 2 caracteres<br>
Transforma em int<br>
Verifica se maior que zero:<br>
sim -> printa a variavel original<br>
nao -> printa a recortada

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Olá, segue abaixo um algoritmo simples com comentários para facilitar o entendimento:

```
String convertInt(Double duplo){
    String sDouble = Double.toString(duplo); //Convertendo para String para retornar uma String adaptando ao seu contexto.

    StringBuilder doisUltimosCharacteres = new StringBuilder(); //StringBuilder representativo apenas para pegarmos os 2 últimos caracteres do valor recebido como parâmetro

    doisUltimosCharacteres.append(sDouble.charAt(sDouble.length() -2 )); //Pega o penultimo valor da String...
    doisUltimosCharacteres.append(sDouble.charAt(sDouble.length() -1)); //... e concatena com o último para verificarmos se esses dois ultimos caracteres são '.0'

    if(doisUltimosCharacteres.toString().equals(".0")){ //Aqui validamos se os dois ultimos caracteres são '.0', se for, retornamos o valor como desejado  
        return sDouble.substring(0, sDouble.length() -2);
    }

    return sDouble; //retorna o valor enviado por parâmetro sem modificações.
}
```

Bons estudos!

Answer (score 4):

Olá, amigo! 
Você pode usar o [DecimalFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html).
Exemplo:

```
Double price = 5.000;
DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("0.#");
System.out.println(format.format(price));
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Abraços,

Answer (score 2):

A solução usando o `DecimalFormat` é a mais adequada. Porém, se quiser tratar usando `String` puramente, então podemos usar o `replace` com o padrão adequado da expressão regular.

Faltou-lhe colocar uma âncora de final de string no `replace` e também escapar o meta-caracter ponto. Por padrão, o `replace` vai substituir o primeiro trecho que casa com o padrão passado. Para forçar substituir apenas o `.0` no final, precisamos fazer o seguinte:

1. escapar o ponto com contrabarra `\`
2. por a âncora de fim de linha `$`

Como o Java (anterior ao 12) sempre interpreta a string, fazendo a substituição dos escapes, então precisamos escapar o contrabarra. O padrão fica assim:

```
"\\.0$"
```

Então a chamada inteira do `replace` fica assim:

```
stringValue.replace("\\.0$", "");
```

Se for usar [*raw strings* do Java 12](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/346337/64969) (que vai ser lançado em março/2019), o código ficaria assim:

```
stringValue.replace(`\.0$`, "");
```