# Raw String Literals Java

Tags: java, string, java-12

Vi que no JDK 12 é possível fazer raw string literals semelhante a algumas linguagens de programação como C#, JS, R etc.

Ex em C#:

```
"Essa não é uma \n raw string";
```

Saída:

> ```
> Essa não  é uma
>  raw string
> ```

```
@"Essa é uma \n raw string";
```

Saída:

> ```
> Essa é uma \n raw string
> ```

Minha dúvida é: como usar esse recurso no JDK 12?

Comment: Cancelaram a entrada dessa funcionalidade no Java 12 =( Atualizei minha resposta com esse cancelamento

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## JEP cancelada

A equipe do OpenJDK anunciou via Twitter em Dezembro/2018 que [esta JEP fora cancelada do Java 12](https://twitter.com/openjdk/status/1075464065248448512?s=21).

Os motivos oficiais foram [expostos aqui](https://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/jdk-dev/2018-December/002402.html). Vale ressaltar que essa funcionalidade foi removida ainda em estado de *preview feature*, e segundo o Brian Goetz a data pra se tornar uma funcionalidade permanente ainda está factível. Possivelmente a versão definitiva seja implementada de modo diferente a que eu descrevi abaixo, principalmente porque houve uma recepção negativa muito forte ao uso dos tiques e, também, a possibilidade de abrir com quantidade arbitrária de tiques.

Dito isso, não é mais possível usar essa funcionalidade na versão GA do Java 12 e, portanto, obtê-lo a fim de testar essa funcionalidade será em vão.

A resposta abaixo continua apenas por interesse histórico.

---

### Usando o JDK 12

Antes de começar a resposta propriamente dita, como foi pedido na pergunta "como usar esse recurso no jdk 12?", é melhor primeiro indicar como ter acesso ao JDK 12 e usá-lo.

Para baixar o build mais recente, visite a página https://jdk.java.net/12/ e baixe o build para a plataforma de sua escolha. Saiba que existem funcionalidades em *early access* (EA), e que as funcionalidades que não forem estáveis o suficiente não irão para *general availability* (GA).

Portanto, se está pretendendo usar alguma funcionalidade nova do JDK 12 em produção, fique atento para saber se ela passou da fase de EA e está pronta para GA. Caso contrário, ela não estará disponível no build final (GA).

### A proposta para raw strings

Segundo a [JEP 326](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/326), que contém essa proposta, basta usar os *ticks* (o caracter "`", também conhecido como acento grave).

A maior mudança dessa JEP é na gramática do Java, alterando a especificação de literais contidas na seção [§3.10 da JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10). A alteração foi adicionar uma produção a mais do não-terminal `Literal` e as produções do novo não-terminal, o `RawStringLiteral`.

> BNF antiga:
>
> ```
> Literal:
>     IntegerLiteral
>     FloatingPointLiteral
>     BooleanLiteral
>     CharacterLiteral
>     StringLiteral
>     NullLiteral
> ```
>
> BNF nova:
>
> ```
> Literal:
>     IntegerLiteral
>     FloatingPointLiteral
>     BooleanLiteral
>     CharacterLiteral
>     StringLiteral
>     RawStringLiteral
>     NullLiteral
> ```
>
> Produções relativas a `RawStringLiteral` introduzidas:
>
> ```
> RawStringLiteral:
>     RawStringDelimiter RawInputCharacter {RawInputCharacter} RawStringDelimiter
> RawStringDelimiter:
>     ` { ` }
> ```
>
> **Nota:**
>
> Na BNF da JLS, tudo que está dentro de chaves está sujeito à Estrela de Kleene; portanto, `` "` { ` } " `` equivaleria à regex ``` "``*" ``` (*tick*, *tick*, Estrela de Kleene `*`)

Leia mais sobre gramáticas e BNF:

- [O que é Backus-Naur Form (BNF)?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/178720/64969)
- [O que é uma linguagem livre de contexto?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/180927/64969)
- [O que é uma meta linguagem?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/215963/64969)

Exemplos, cada string terminada por um `;`:

````
`tem uma contrabarra no fim\`;
``com dois ticks abrindo, posso por `tick` no meio da frase a vontade``;
```se abro com n ticks, fecho com os mesmos n ticks```;
`pode fazer
 múltiplas
 linhas se assim
 desejar`;
`no final da frase não quebro a linha\n`;
````

Para fazer a interpretação desses escapes de maneira tradicional, tem o método de instância `unescape`. Então, o seguinte código Java

```
String ex = `uma frase
outra frase\ne por fim!`;
System.out.println("1:" + ex + ":1");
System.out.println("2:" + ex.unescape() + ":2");
```

imprime as seguintes linhas:

```
1:uma frase
outra frase\ne por fim!:1
2:uma frase
outra frase
e por fim!:2
```

Uma raw string só se diferencia de uma string tradicional a nível de escrita de código-fonte, sendo então uma string padrão para a JVM. Portanto, a JEP adicionou uma função nova do compilador (identificando os *ticks* para raw string) e o método de instância `String.unescape()` já descrito aqui. Existem outros métodos adicionais que a JEP propõe, que tem como foco auxiliar <strike>a preguiça</strike> a estética de código com raw strings. Não entrarei em detalhes, mas vou enumerar os novos métodos de `String` que achei na JEP (todos são métodos de instância):

- `String unescape()` (já citado)
- `String align()`
- `String align(int)`
- `String indent(int)`
- `<R> R transform(Function<String, R> f)`

Vale ressaltar que essa JEP é uma *preview language feature*, que, como definido na [JEP 12](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/12), é colocado como uma *feature* temporária para provocar discussões e analisar impactos na vida do programador em seu ambiente real.

### Criticismo à JEP 326 por mim

O primeiro ponto que achei estranho, muito estranho, é que na escrita dessa JEP foi usado o atributo `String.length`, enquanto que eu conhecia apenas o método `String.length()`. Tem até uma [discussão sobre isso aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/208880/64969).

> ```
> boolean b2 = `\n`.length == 2;
> ```

Até procurei por mudanças quanto a isso nas JEPs dos JDKs 10 e 11, assim como dei uma olhada por cima nas mudanças do JDK 9, mas não encontrei nada referente a isso, ao fato de `.length` ter virado um atributo **ou** um açúcar sintático para não precisar dos parênteses. Não achei, apesar de que iria ficar grato caso isso ocorresse.

O outro ponto é que, quando comparando com strings literais / raw strings de outras plataformas, eles colocaram que no Python é apenas com [aspas triplicadas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/80551/64969), quando na verdade são [começadas com `r"`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/80545/64969).

> ```
> """...""" Groovy, Kotlin, Python, Scala, Swift
> ```
>
> Python, Kotlin, Groovy and Swift have opted to use triple double quotes to indicate raw strings.

As aspas triplicadas em Python servem na verdade para [strings multi-linhas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/80551/64969).

Então, parece-me que essa JEP teve uma falta de zelo no aspecto de comparação com o Python, e que a ausência dos parênteses no método `.length()` foi por mania de programador (ou então por ser uma *feature* que entrou e eu não consegui reparar em seu surgimento).

Comment: Sobre o `boolean b2 = `\n`.length == 2;`. Isso deve ser apenas um erro de digitação na JEP. Não há atributo algum público com o nome `lenght` na classe `String`. Se você tentar compilar esse código, o seguinte erro é apresentado: "error: cannot find symbol boolean b2 = `\n`.length == 2;" (apontando o erro no caractere ".").

Comment: @FelipeMarinho imaginei algo assim. Mas na minha opinião é extremamente feio que um engano desses passe em uma proposta de melhoria oficial. Poderiam pelo menos ter corrigido a redação em alguma revisão ou algo assim. Faltou zelo na escrita da JEP

Comment: @FelipeMarinho Essa classe acredito que não seja a String, pelo que lí na JEP 326 que você me passou a classe será RawStringDelimiter.

Comment: `RawStringDelimiter` é parte da gramática do Java, alterando a JLS, não uma classe nova

Comment: @ayowoleagbedejobi, sobre gramáticas: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/178720/64969, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/180927/64969, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/215963/64969 (coloquei os links em ordem de importância para melhorar especificamente o seu entendimento no assunto)

Comment: @ayowoleagbedejobi, editei a resposta para cobrir a questão das gramáticas; espero ter sido claro, mas fiz na pressa

Comment: Entendi, achei que seria uma classe nova